# Add up digit from char array in c language

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, c-strings

I am new to `C` programming and trying to make a program to add up the digits from the input like this:

```
input = 12345 <= 5 digit
output = 15 <= add up digit
```

I try to convert the `char` index to `int` but it dosent seems to work! Can anyone help?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
   char nilai[5];
   int j,length,nilai_asli=0,i;
   printf("nilai: ");
   scanf("%s",&nilai);
   length = strlen(nilai);

   for(i=0; i<length; i++){
        int nilai1 = nilai[i];
        printf("%d",nilai1);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
nilai: 12345
4950515253
```

Comment: Always, always **validate your input** by **checking the return** of whatever function you are using, e.g. `if (scanf("%s",&nilai) != 1) { fputs ("user canceled input.\n", stderr); return 1; }` Otherwise, if you don't get the input you are expecting and call `strlen(nilai);` on an uninitialized array -- bad things happen...

Comment: Off-topic: Prefer using English only identifiers. Some day you *will* share code with people not capable to understand your mother tongue (and if only here on SO) – but having to guess the intention of a function or variable makes it pretty difficult to provide appropriate help...

Comment: Be aware that arrays decay to pointers automatically. So when passing an array to where a pointer is required, just pass it directly (i. e. `scanf("%s", nilai)`). Applying the addressof operator to an array produces a pointer to a different type (`char(*)[5]` in given case). The whole matter only 'works' because scanf converts back to `char*` internally...

Answer (score 3):

You have *two* problems with the code you show.

First lets talk about the problem you ask about... You display the encoded character value. All characters in C are encoded in one way or another. The most common encoding scheme is called [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) where the digits are encoded with `'0'` starting at `48` up to `'9'` at `57`.

Using this knowledge it should be quite easy to figure out a way to convert a digit character to the integer value of the digit: Subtract the character `'0'`. As in

```
int nilai1 = nilai[i] - '0';  // "Convert" digit character to its integer value
```

---

Now for the second problem: Strings in C are really called ***null-terminated*** byte strings. That *null-terminated* bit is quite important, and all strings functions (like `strlen`) will look for that to know when the string ends.

When you input five character for the `scanf` call, the `scanf` function will write the null-terminator on the *sixth* position in the five-element array. That is *out of bounds* and leads to *undefined behavior*.

You can solve this by either making the array longer, or by telling `scanf` not to write more characters into the array than it can actually fit:

```
scanf("%4s", nilai);  // Read at most four characters
                      // which will fit with the terminator in a five-element array
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your buffer isn't big enough. String input is null-terminated, so if you want to read in your output `12345` of `5` numbers, you need a buffer of at least `6` chars:

```
char nilai[6];
```

And if your input is bigger than `5` chars, then your buffer has to be bigger, too.

But the problem with adding up the digits is that you're not actually adding up anything. You're just assigning to `int nilai1` over and over and discarding the result. Instead, put `int nilai1` before the loop and increase it in the loop. Also, to convert from a `char` to the `int` it represents, subtract `'0'`. All in all this part should look like this:

```
int nilai1 = 0;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    nilai1 += nilai[i] - '0';
}
printf("%d\n", nilai1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

This character array

```
char nilai[5];
```

can not contain a string with 5 digits. Declare the array with at least one more character to store the terminating zero of a string.

```
char nilai[6];
```

In the call of scanf

```
scanf("%s",&nilai);
```

remove the operator `&` before the name `nilai`. And such a call is unsafe. You could use for example the standard function `fgets`.

This call

```
length = strlen(nilai);
```

is redundant and moreover the variable `length` should be declared having the type `size_t`.

This loop

```
   for(i=0; i<length; i++){
        int nilai1 = nilai[i];
        printf("%d",nilai1);
   }
```

entirely does not make sense.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 6 };
    char nilai[N];

    printf( "nilai: ");
    fgets( nilai, sizeof( nilai ), stdin );

    int nilai1 = 0;

    for ( const char *p = nilai; *p != '\0'; ++p )
    {
        if ( isdigit( ( unsigned char ) *p ) ) nilai1 += *p - '0';  
    }

    printf( "%d\n", nilai1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
nilai: 12345
15
```